# Why do my DateTime objects behave differently?

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have a script that checks for certain logs between two times `$startDate` and `$endDate` using `Search-UnifiedAuditLog` where `$startDate` is found by checking a line in a .txt file and `$endDate` is the current time. I run this as shown below.

```
$startDate = Get-Content $logPath -Last 1
$startDate = [datetime]$startDate
$startDate = $startDate.AddHours(-1)
$endDate = (Get-Date)
```

This particular script is run every hour, so the time between `$startDate` and `$endDate` is two hours (due to the AddHours). If I check the value of these variables, they are indeed two hours apart. However, when I run the script, it goes through the previous 6 hours of logs. This makes me think it is assuming that $startDate is in UTC, and it is converting it to my time zone. Is this what it is doing, and if so, how can I get my script to only check for logs one hour before the time listed in my .txt document?

Comment: If the timestamps are indeed correct, the bug could be in loop logic. A `DateTime` doesn't contain timezone information, but try and see if `.ToUniversalTime()` would provide surprising results.

Comment: You can check the `.Kind` property of the `$startDate` variable. This can be either `Local`, `Utc` or `Unspecified`. See [DateTimeKind Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=netframework-4.8). In case of `Unspecified`, since .NET 2.0, [_"This instance of DateTime is assumed to be a UTC time, and the conversion is performed as if Kind were Utc."_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: Can you include the date from the file in your post?

Comment: @Theo You were correct. I changed the kind to Local and that seems to have resolved my issue. If you submit it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer

You can check the `.Kind` property of the `$startDate` variable.
This property can be either **Local**, **Utc** or **Unspecified**. See [DateTimeKind Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimekind?view=netframework-4.8).

In case of **Unspecified**, since .NET 2.0, "*This instance of DateTime is assumed to be a UTC time, and the conversion is performed as if Kind were Utc.*" as stated in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks)